# Converting a tex file to pdf

Tags: miktex, compiling, texstudio, windows

I use TexStudio to create a tex file and save it in my DropBox in the Cloud. I then use CloudConvert to make a pdf file, which I then save on my Windows Pc.

This works OK, but isn't there a simpler, more direct way? I'd like to execute a Windows program which inputs a tex file and outputs a pdf file.

I have MiKTeX installed on my PC.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! You can have a look at [our starter guide](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) to familiarize yourself further with our format.

Comment: If you use TeXStudio to create your `tex` file, then, go to the Tools, and then either `build view` or `compile`.  If it is configured correctly for MikTeX it will generate a pdf for you.

Comment: It's already been pointed out that you should just run the typesetting system from within your editor (or if you don't get on with that editor, pick another one!), but I wonder how you ended up with this odd set up in the first place.

Answer (score 2):

Since you already have TeXStudio installed, if you also have a LaTeX distribution installed in your system you can just compile your `.tex` file within TexStudio: it will create a pdf file in the same folder, which will be synced by Dropbox.